# Pulling in an Instagram feed of image to my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram

I'm using some JS to pull in a feed of Instagram images from my account by a certain hashtag associated with the image.

I've set it to pull in 10 images but for some reason it seem to be pulling in 21 instead.

This was working ok a few days ago but all of a sudden it's not working now and have no idea why

Here's the page online http://www.gezzamondo.co.uk/simple.html

```
// JavaScript Document
$(function() {
var cmdURL, embedImage, onPhotoLoaded, param, tag_name, userid,
    param = {
        access_token: "I'VE REMOVED THIS", // feel free to change it with your own access token
        count: 10 // the total number of images
    },
    tag = 'Gezzamondoportfolio', // your user id. you can find this one out by looking into one of your pictures uri
    tag_name = '#photowall',
    cmdURL = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + tag + '/media/recent?callback=?';

embedImage = function(photo) {
    var a, img;
    img = $('<img/>').attr({
        //'src': photo.images.thumbnail.url,
        //'width': photo.images.thumbnail.width,
        //'height': photo.images.thumbnail.height
        'src': photo.images.standard_resolution.url,
        'width': photo.images.standard_resolution.width,
        'height': photo.images.standard_resolution.height
    });
    a = $('<a />').attr({
        'href': photo.images.standard_resolution.url,
        'target': '_blank',
        'class': 'pull-left'
    }).append(img).appendTo(tag_name);
};

onPhotoLoaded = function(data) {
    var photo, _i, _len, _ref, _results;
    if (data.meta.code === 200 && data.data) {
        _ref = data.data;
        _results = [];
        for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
            photo = _ref[_i];
            _results.push(embedImage(photo));
        }
        return _results;
    }
 };
 return $.getJSON(cmdURL, param, onPhotoLoaded);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the [count](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent) parameter into your request URL:

```
cmdURL = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + tag + '/media/recent?count=10&callback=?';
```

(edit) You could also only count to 10 in your for loop where you build your photos:

```
for (_i = 0, _len < 10; _i < _len; _i++) {
photo = _ref[_i];
_results.push(embedImage(photo));}
```

Obviously this won't change the number of results you get back from Instagram but it will cap the number you output to screen...

Comment: That didn't seem to change anything

Comment: If i change the amount to 8 or 9 it pulls in the correct amount.  Anything from 10 upwards it seems to display 21 images instead of the requested amount

Comment: @Gezzamondo if you're asking where the for code goes, it's in your onPhotoLoaded function. Just change _len=_ref.length; to _len<10;